# Meteor - jQuery nth-child selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, meteor

Whilst picking up the values of a dynamic form list.

I have the following code on the template.js file.

```
var count = $("#marker").children().length;

var partList = [];

for(var x=1; x<count+1; x++){

  var fName = $("#marker.parts:nth-child(x)").find('input.fName').val();
  var lName = $("#marker.parts:nth-child(x)").find('input.lName').val();
  var eMail = $("#marker.parts:nth-child(x)").find('input.eMail').val();
  var date = $("#marker.parts:nth-child(x)").find('input.datepicker').val();

  object = {fName: fName, lName: lName, eMail: eMail, date: date};
  partList.push(object);
}
return partList;
```

The form is full of values that are strings.

When I run - in the browser console the error reads:
*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child*

However if I write the jQuery statement directly into the browser console.

```
e.g. $("#marker.parts:nth-child(1)").find('input.fName').val();
```

eh voila. the form values are picked up correctly. And tested on each input field within the form it doesn't break and picks up the correct form value.

Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Thanks

relevant parts of the html templates:

```
<template name="createNewEvent">
<form id="createForm">
<!--......other form components are here....-->
<section id="marker">
{{#each friendInput}}
    <div class='parts'>Name of Participant : <input type='text' class="fName"
        placeholder='First Name'> <input type='text' class="lName" placeholder='Last
        Name'> Email Address : <input id="searchBox" type='text' placeholder='email           
        address of friend' class="eMail"> Date for Hosting: {{> add_part}}</div>
{{/each}}
</section>
</form>
</template>

<template name="add_part">
    <input class="datepicker" id="date-id" name="date">
</template>
```

The friendInput helper is just returning an array with the correct number to iterate over.

Comment: try :eq in place of :nth-child here!!

Comment: @zakir2k, are you looking for an element that has both the ID marker and the class parts, or are you looking for `.parts` inside of `#marker`?

Comment: my form template is repeated depending on another user selection.so therefore I am looking at the div elements with class .parts inside of #marker. the $("#marker").children().length comes up with the correct number of div elements. i wanted to avoid using ids as i am using repeated templates. let me add the template code.

Comment: for `.parts` inside of `#marker`, your selector should be `#marker .parts` (note the space between)

Comment: @zakir2k, seeing your html template, you're going to end up with duplicate `#searchBox`, it shouldn't affect this code but shouldn't be there and might cause other problems.

Comment: @smerny good spot. thanks. now it does work.

Comment: @smerny aah yes- will sort that out too. cheers

Comment: @zakir2k, you should still be doing a `.map()` or atleast an `.each()` instead... you can loop through each `.parts` like this `$("#marker .parts").each( function() { var $this = $(this); var fName = $this.find("input.fName").val(); /* etc.. create object and push*/ });`

Comment: @smerny that does look more efficient. let me try and implement. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `x` is a variable, use it like this

```
for(var x=1; x<count+1; x++){

  var fName = $("#marker.parts:nth-child("+x+")").find('input.fName').val();
  var lName = $("#marker.parts:nth-child("+x+")").find('input.lName').val();
  var eMail = $("#marker.parts:nth-child("+x+")").find('input.eMail').val();
  var date = $("#marker.parts:nth-child("+x+")").find('input.datepicker').val();

  object = {fName: fName, lName: lName, eMail: eMail, date: date};
  partList.push(object);
}
```

In your code `x` will treat as string `x` only. It wont act as a variable there. Thats why it showing the error

Comment: thanks - the error doesn't appear anymore - however with your code it's not picking up any values. all the selected values are undefined.

Comment: as per @smerny comment. need to put a space between #marker and .parts in the jQuery selector.